how to replace strings with varying number of spaces by null on all columns
I have a lot of legacy tables on a PostgreSQL database, that have missing values as blank string values (which can vary in the number of spaces they contain). I am looking for a query that allows to replace them by null.
Ideally, this code should be applicable to any table, fetching column names from information_schema.colums

You can use regular expressions to match strings consisting of only blanks.

which can vary in the number of spaces they contain .. WHERE TRIM(column) = ''? fetching column names from information_schema.colums Use dynamic SQL.
